# Spring: Does AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests lazy load beans?

Tags: java, spring, testing

My legacy code uses [`AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/test/AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests.html) to facilitate its unit tests. 
As far as I can see when I specify a Spring configuration file in my getConfigLocations it lazy loads all beans

I've been looking at the Spring documentation but I don't see this being mentioned.

So just wish to confirm that this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You must define a bean with `lazy-init=true` or set `default-lazy-init=true` in beans tag to lazy init them.  `AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests` load context from setup() method, that is final.

Comment: So the only way for lazy loading to take place across an application context is to set the beans tag with "default-lazy-init=true" ?

Comment: Or in Configuaration or Lazy annotations if using JavaConfig.

Comment: No we are not using JavaConfig